# Applying font styles in OpenGL and FreeType library

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to display a text in my application (c++) using openGL and the freetype library.
since now, I can draw this text but not with font style specified.
is there anyone have an idea about the origin of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

FreeType does not provide a "mapping table" from font names to the actual file names. One font contains a single collection of characters, each of them in one style. So if you have, e.g. the "arial.ttf" file and it is not italic, then you have to find the "arial_italic.ttf" file which contains the italic version of the font. Do not understand me wrong: adding the "_italic" suffix does not give you the correct file name :)

There's a discussion here http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/freetype/2009-04/msg00020.html

EDIT (strikeouts & underlines):

Both of these effects are simple horizontal lines. All you have to do is to specify the thickness and vertical position of the line. Some of FreeType's loaders contain the code to load  StrikeoutSize/StrikeoutPosition and UnderlineThickness/UnderlinePosition. I didn't do it myself, so just take a look at the sources using the "strikeout" searchword.

Comment: so, it seems that my "mapping table" dosen't give me the right font file from font_name (with style that i want).
Have you an idea (piste) trying to resolve this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Indeed. I had an error in my code of "mapping table", thanks.
Still another question: how to apply font effects (strickeout, inderline) ?